# Number of different user's IDs occured in the table more than 3 times

Tags: mysql, sql, database, count

I have a task to do, there is a table with different user IDs and SQL query should count the number of different users ids that occured in the table more than 3 times. For example IDs number that occured in the table is 1, 1,  2, 1, 3, 4, 3, 3 ,1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4 since number 1, 3 and 4 occured in the table more than 3 time SQL query should return just one row number 3.
What i have done so far is:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) counter 
   FROM (SELECT COUNT(id) as counter_id FROM user_id GROUP BY id HAVING COUNT(id) >3)
```

I am not sure is that one correct if it is incorrect what will be correct one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to run your query?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) counter
FROM (SELECT COUNT(id) as counter_id
      FROM user_id
      GROUP BY id
      HAVING COUNT(id) > 3
     )
```

If so, you would get an error, because the subquery in the `FROM` clause requires an alias.    In addition, it is strange that a table would be called `user_id`.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) counter
FROM (SELECT COUNT(id) as counter_id
      FROM user_id
      GROUP BY id
      HAVING COUNT(id) > 3
     ) u
-------^
```

Answer (score 0):

use `distinct` inside count() and take only id from subquery output

```
select count(distinct id) from ( SELECT id  
FROM user GROUP BY id 
HAVING COUNT(id) >3) a
```